# how to scan wifi every minute android

Tags: android, timer, wifi, onresume

I have use timertask to rescan wifi every 10 second , but it only works when I resume to the activity. how can it be automatically update wifi signal after I start the activty?

```
 protected void onResume() {

        tim.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                wifi.startScan();
                wifiLists = wifi.getScanResults();
            }
        },0,10000);

            for (int i = 0; i < wifiLists.size(); i++) {
                if(wifiLists.get(i).SSID.equals( "eduroam"))
                {
                    mSSID.setText("SSID: "   + wifiLists.get(i).SSID);
                    mLevel.setText("Level: " + String.valueOf(wifiLists.get(i).level));
                    mFreq.setText("Freq: " + String.valueOf(wifiLists.get(i).frequency));
                }
            }
        super.onResume();
    }
```

Comment: Try puting your code in service

Comment: AlarmManager + BroadcastReceiver thats what you need.

Answer (score 0):

for checking thing in period time you should use services in android.
services are always run in background unless user stop service.